# why my canvas.toDataURL don't work?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I use fabric.js-2.0.0-beta.4 for my project.

```
 var data = saas.canvas.toDataURL({
      format: 'png',
     left:100,
     top:100,
     width:200,
     height:100
 });
```

It don't work with the code above, but when I remove `width` and `height`:

```
var data = saas.canvas.toDataURL({
     format: 'png',
     left:100,
     top:100,
 });
```

It's fine

Why?

Comment: use [fabric1.7.17](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.min.js), why you work with beta, choose a stable one? check working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/NfZVb/495/)

Comment: What actually does not work? do you get a blank canvas? or an error?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi its a blank canvas, its working in 1.7.17, not with new beta.

Comment: i think is fixed then with the latest beta that is not published. You can pull down it from fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js if you want to try it or maybe build from current master branch.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi yep cool, with beta 6 , its working.

Comment: I will add an explanative answer, just for history things.

Comment: @Durga one of the very good reasons to work with fabric 2.0.0-beta.4 is to have a version of Fabric which works with zoneJs > 0.8.5 (currently : 0.8.14) and which doesn't create new listeners on each action you do on angular app (this issue leaded to have frozen app after +/- 20 operations from user).

Comment: Any reason why older fabric do not work with newer zonejs?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually a bug appened between beta2 and beta6 of fabricjs.
Currently solved as 27/08/2017 in the current github master branch.